# Catch ON_EN_CHANGE for a group of EditBox controls

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I need to catch ON_EN_CHANGE message for a group of CEdit controls and process it in terms of the specific CEdit control id.
I need something similar to :

```
ON_COMMAND_RANGE(IDC_EDT_KEY_1,IDC_EDT_KEY_7,OnKeyChange)
```

But for ON_EN_CHANGE message.
Is that even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ON_CONTROL_RANGE is the equivalent for control notification messages.